# CSS two column layout not horizontally aligned

Tags: html, css

I want "About This Page" and "Around the web" to be horizontally aligned.

Also, open to any suggestions for improving this snippet of code. I just want to have a responsive / simple two column layout behind a wide colored background.

```css
.footer-above {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.footer-links,
.built-with {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-above">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="built-with">
            <h3>ABOUT THIS PAGE</h3>
            <p> Made with HTML5Boilerplate</p>
         </div><!--built-with-->
         <div class="footer-links">
            <h3>AROUND THE WEB</h3>
         </div><!--footer-links-->
    </div><!--container-->
</div><!-- footer-above -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using **[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)** for this, which can be achieved by simply adding:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

If you want to have both boxes occupy the same height, you'll need a fixed `height` on `.footer-links` and `.built-with`. I've gone with `150px` in the following example:

```css
.footer-above {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.footer-links,
.built-with {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 40%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-above">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="built-with">
      <h3>ABOUT THIS PAGE</h3>
      <p> Made with HTML5Boilerplate</p>
    </div><!--built-with-->
    <div class="footer-links">
      <h3>AROUND THE WEB</h3>
    </div><!--footer-links-->
  </div><!--container-->
</div><!-- footer-above -->
```

Flexbox **[has support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flex)** in every browser apart from Internet Explorer (though it's coming to IE as well). If you'd like to support Internet Explorer as well, you can use `vertical-align: middle` along with `display: inline-block`, as is demonstrated in **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7310398/2341603)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: hmm but i wanted container to be 960px , so I could run media queries later.

Comment: You can always include that as well; it won't affect the `flex` :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `flex`. Read about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.footer-above {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    padding-top: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}

.footer-links,
.built-with {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-above">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="built-with">
            <h3>ABOUT THIS PAGE</h3>
            <p> Made with HTML5Boilerplate</p>
         </div><!--built-with-->
         <div class="footer-links">
            <h3>AROUND THE WEB</h3>
         </div><!--footer-links-->
    </div><!--container-->
</div><!-- footer-above -->
```

Comment: do you have a non-flexbox solution as well out of curiosity. By the way, this made overrode `margin:0auto` so its no longer center aligned

Comment: you can use `table` & `table-cell`

Answer (score 1):

Use table-cell as display property

```
.footer-links,
.built-with {
    display: table-cell;
    max-width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

I think , it'll horizontally aligned these boxes

Comment: isn't tables a bad practice though, I thought it should be semantically reserved for actual tables though

Comment: True, but that doesn't mean you can't be flexible when it comes to solving problems.

Comment: well , you said you need them to be horizontally aligned. That's what this answer is all about nothing else. you can also use "display:inline-table".

Answer (score 0):

this is based off of obsidian ages answer since it wasn't updated to match my exact question.

I edited `.footer-above` to 1400px since `width:100%` with code doesn't scale as viewport width changes.

Also, it should be `align-items: flex-start;` on `container` class, since i want a baseline at the top of parent div

```css
.footer-above {
  width: 1400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.footer-links,
.built-with {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height: 150px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 960px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-above">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="built-with">
      <h3>ABOUT THIS PAGE</h3>
      <p> Made with HTML5Boilerplate</p>
    </div><!--built-with-->
    <div class="footer-links">
      <h3>AROUND THE WEB</h3>
    </div><!--footer-links-->
  </div><!--container-->
</div><!-- footer-above -->
```